# How to enter array objects into NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

sortedArray contains 100+ objects that need to be organize by the 'hour' in the 'time' key. The outcome is to have an array of arrays to populate the sections of a table and use the hour for the index. 'time' is of the form - 2012-05-15 07:20:00

```
NSInteger d = 0;
NSInteger prevd;
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
detailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
    [detailArray addObject:[NSNull null]];

for (NSArray *item in sortedArray) {
    prevd = d;
    d = [[[[item objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"time"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 2)] intValue];
    if (d > prevd && prevd != 0) {
        [detailArray replaceObjectAtIndex:d withObject:tempArray];
        [tempArray removeAllObjects];
    }
    [tempArray addObject:item];
}
```

The objects are not ending up in the correct detailArray postition or not ending up in it at all. For instance, `[detailArray objectAtIndex:6]` give items with time 14 (2pm).
What am I missing?

**Edit to correct code with 1st answer.** It is now:

```
NSInteger d = 0;
NSInteger prevd;
NSMutableArray *tempArray = nil;
detailArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 24; ++i)
    [detailArray addObject:[NSNull null]];

for (NSArray *item in sortedArray) {
    prevd = d;
    d = [[[[item objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"time"] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 2)] intValue];
    if (d > prevd) {
        tempArray = NSMutableArray array];
        [detailArray replaceObjectAtIndex:d withObject:tempArray];
    }
    [tempArray addObject:item];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reuse tempArray like that, you're going to end up with detailArray containing multiple entries that all point to the same tempArray instance. (i.e. every slot that had a time is going to end up with the array for the last time slot).

Instead of

```
[detailArray replaceObjectAtIndex:d withObject:tempArray];
[tempArray removeAllObjects];
```

you'll want

```
tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[detailArray replaceObjectAtIndex:d withObject:tempArray];
```

that way each time slot has its own array.
And you'll also want to change your original declaration of tempArray to be

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = nil;
```

Comment: These changes worked. A few more answers please: Why the `NSMutableArray *tempArray = nil` declaration? (I'm assuming that should be line 3 of original) That has what effect? Doesn't `tempArray = [NSMutableArray array]` create and return a new object each time? Is a new & different tempArray object created when that is run? And second, why the order 'create' and then 'replace'? (the 2 lines in middle group of code) Isn't tempArray empty when its placed in detailArray on the next line?

Comment: remember that replaceObjectAtIndex does't copy the array, it just holds a reference to it, so you need to do the create first, otherwise when you put it in detail array, it'll still have the previous slots values in it.